# Excel 2010 VBA Prompt and Uncheck on Checkbox Click

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, excel-2010

I have a columns of checkboxes in Excel. When one of them is checked, I want to prompt the user "Are you sure?" or something to that effect. If they answer "Yes", move on and do nothing. If they answer no, I want to uncheck the box (the one they just clicked).
It seems simple enough, but I can't for some reason get it to work.

I've tried something like:

```
r = MsgBox("Are you sure", vbYesNo, "Eh?")
If r <> vbYes Then Application.Undo
```

But that doesn't quite work. It seems so simple, yet it ends up being a pain.

Comment: Please tell us more about `doesn't work`? Did you try to use the [Click event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211343%28v=office.11%29.aspx)? You will have to create one for each checkbox but that should work.

Comment: What type of checkbox did you use, a Form Control or Active X?

Comment: Are the checkboxes on a form, or on a worksheet ?

Comment: I've tried embedding it directly in the click event, and created a sub called during the click event. Upon some google searching, I found that Application.Undo will not undo a VBA command. This is a form control on a worksheet directly (no user form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that checking a checkbox doesn't trigger an Excel action that can be undone.  (Doesn't matter if the controls are Form or ActiveX.)

If your checkboxes **are** ActiveX controls then you can do this:

```
Private Sub VerifyCheckBox(chk As CheckBox)
   If chk.Value Then ' only ask question if checkbox has been checked
      If MsgBox("Are you sure", vbYesNo, "Eh?") <> vbYes Then
         chk.Value = Not chk.Value
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

You would then call that in each checkbox's click event.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
   VerifyCheckBox CheckBox1
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
   VerifyCheckBox CheckBox2
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you just made the light bulb go off. They are not ActiveX controls, they are form controls. I didn't know the difference. I'm assuming that form controls are meant to reside on a userForm only and ActiveX controls can be embedded in the workbook directly?

Comment: No not necessarily, a worksheet can be classed as a type of form. You can use either but they each behave quite differently as you have found out.  Obviously they look different as well. Form controls more often used without VBA to control cells and active x controls are used when you need more flexible design requirements. You also have more control over their events. See: [Controls](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-forms-form-controls-and-activex-controls-on-a-worksheet-HA010237663.aspx)